# How to create a dynamic list of the same form on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How do I create a dynamic list of the same form and show it on the view on Yii2 (it can be viewed as a list of the same object with different information) Thanks.

I have the following form on /frontend/views/site/example.php
That form I want to put it on a list.

```
<div class="site-example">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>Example of a list:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-example']); ?>

              <?=  $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $email]) ?>

              <?=  $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $lastname]) ?>

              <?=  $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $phone]) ?>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is your `controller`.

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\Controller;
use frontend\models\YourForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionYourAction()
    {
        $forms = [new YourForm, new YourForm, new YourForm];

        return $this->render('example', [
            'forms' => $forms
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then your `view` could be below

```
<div class="site-example">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>Example of a list:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php foreach ($forms as $index => $form): ?>
                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['id' => "form-example-$index"]]); ?>

                  <?= $form->field($form, "[$index]email")->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $form->email]) ?>

                  <?= $form->field($form, "[$index]lastname")->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $form->lastname]) ?>

                  <?= $form->field($form, "[$index]phone")->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $form->phone]) ?>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I do the following on the controller? $model = new MyForm();
            $forms = [ $model,  $model,  $model];

Comment: Hi @JanBeeck, I have just tried your case, and it works well.

Comment: Thanks @paul for the answer. So the above code would work with 3 forms.

Comment: I have the following controller @paul, how can I modify to do the above task? Thanks.     `public function actionMyModel() { $model = new MyModelForm(); if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) { $model->insertMyModel(); return $this->render('MyModel', ['model' => $model]); } else { return $this->render('MyModel', [ 'model' => $model, ]); } }}// end function`

Comment: I have no idea what exactly do want. If you just want to collect tabular input you may go [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @paul. It really helps a lot, actually I need tabular ouput.